# mongoengine.errors.InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "id"

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, mongoengine, pydantic

In the update,and delete route,and now in Like and Dislike in the api (fastapi) it's giving the same error->mongoengine.errors.InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "id",so to be simpler I'll just use Like as an example,the schema is

> ps : if you're asking yourself,yes I already tried giving it id field and alias with _id and all possibilities that I could think

```
class Like(BaseModel):
    user_id: str
    post_id: str
```

The route is

```
@router.post("/like", status_code=201)
def like(like_data: schemas.Like, current_user: int = Depends(oauth2.get_current_user)):
    new_like = Likes()
    new_like.user_id = like_data.user_id
    post_of_the_like = Post.objects(_id=like_data.post_id)
    post_of_the_like.likes.append(new_like)
    post_of_the_like.save()

    return {"message": "successfully added like"}
```

and the model is

```
class Likes(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):
    user_id = mongoengine.ObjectIdField(required=True)

class Post(mongoengine.Document):
    _id = mongoengine.StringField(default=str(uuid.uuid4()),)

    title = mongoengine.StringField(required=True)
    content = mongoengine.StringField(required=True)

    published = mongoengine.BooleanField(required=True, default=True)
    created_at = mongoengine.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    likes = mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentListField(Likes)
    dislikes = mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentListField(Dislikes)

    comments = mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentListField(Comment)

    type = mongoengine.StringField(required=True, default="post")
    about = mongoengine.StringField(default="The creater did not put an about")
    tags = mongoengine.ListField(mongoengine.StringField())
    banner = mongoengine.StringField(required=False)

    meta = {
        "db_alias": "jc",
        "collection": "posts",
    }
```

and the whole message error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\queryset\transform.py", line 91, in query
    fields = _doc_cls._lookup_field(parts)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\base\document.py", line 1107, in _lookup_field
    raise LookUpError('Cannot resolve field "%s"' % field_name)
mongoengine.errors.LookUpError: Cannot resolve field "id"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\httptools_impl.py", line 375, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 208, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 112, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\cors.py", line 84, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 656, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 259, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 61, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 216, in app
    solved_result = await solve_dependencies(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\fastapi\dependencies\utils.py", line 527, in solve_dependencies
    solved = await run_in_threadpool(call, **sub_values)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\concurrency.py", line 39, in run_in_threadpool
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py", line 28, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(func, *args, cancellable=cancellable,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 805, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 743, in run
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\invis\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\jc_api\.\app\oauth2.py", line 40, in get_current_user
    user=User.objects(id=token_id).first()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\queryset\base.py", line 290, in first
    result = queryset[0]
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\queryset\base.py", line 200, in __getitem__
    queryset._cursor[key],
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\queryset\base.py", line 1645, in _cursor
    self._cursor_obj = self._collection.find(self._query, **self._cursor_args)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\queryset\base.py", line 1694, in _query
    self._mongo_query = self._query_obj.to_query(self._document)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\queryset\visitor.py", line 91, in to_query
    query = query.accept(QueryCompilerVisitor(document))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\queryset\visitor.py", line 184, in accept
    return visitor.visit_query(self)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\queryset\visitor.py", line 80, in visit_query
    return transform.query(self.document, **query.query)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\queryset\transform.py", line 93, in query
    raise InvalidQueryError(e)
mongoengine.errors.InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "id"
```

If anyone could give a hint or opinion of what should help I would appreciate a lot,I searched through github but all examples are either flask or django and use methods that don't apply to this case,and even if you can't help,thanks for reading still here

Answer (score 0):

Few things are wrong in your code snippet but hopefully you'll find the answer below:

```
class Post(mongoengine.Document):
    _id = mongoengine.StringField(default=str(uuid.uuid4()),)
```

- unrelated with your problem but `default` should be a callable, otherwise it gets evaluated once and will return the same value all the time
- You should avoid using "_id" to name your field, "_id" is something used internally by mongoengine.
- Set primary_key=True on the key that is supposed to be the primary key (i.e what gets saved in the document as "_id" when translating MongoENgine -> pymongo document)

Typically your primary key should be defined like (below is the default id that gets defined if you don't provide one)

```
id = ObjectIdField(default=ObjectId, primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Hi!Thanks for the feedback,it helped a lot !!

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how could I use callable in default?

Comment: for your uuid4, it would be default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()), for an objectId it would be  default=ObjectId. Basically you just give a function (callable) that will be evaluated whenever an object is created

Comment: Consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer if it helped :)

Comment: Thanks so much !!! Yes I already tried before upvoting your answer because it was A LOT useful,but it always gives me a modal saying "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: alright no problem

Comment: Have a great year !